# How does EJB home object reference knows the server details to which it should connect?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

After I do a JNDI look up , what I get is a reference to the Home of EJB Object.
But when I do an API call on Home/Remote , how does it find the URL/port of the server ?

Thanks
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RMI makes this possible. The local objects you get on the client side are called *stubs* and *know how to look over the network* for their remote counterpart through RMI/IIOP. Quoting [Understanding Java RMI Internals](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3455311/Understanding-Java-RMI-Internals.htm):

> The client has NO idea on which machine and to which port the server is listening. But, it has a stub object that knows all these. So, the client can invoke the desired method of the stub.

I also suggest to check this very nice article (a bit old but still nice) on TheServerSide: [Under the Hood of J2EE Clustering](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364410/Under-the-Hood-of-J2EE-Clustering) (starting from **EJB clustering implementation**). It covers more than your initial question but is very interesting.